# php show specific site menu based on user login name

Tags: php, mysql

I have a site that has a menu for non members and one for members which is shown depending on if the user is logged in or logged out but would like to know how to have an additional menu that is only show to a specific user upon their login by using the user email address to determine that user is shown the third menu.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Use session to check if the user is logged in and display contents. Also update question and add your code.

Comment: Add your code if you would like more help and implementation!

Answer (score 0):

**Try this out!**

```
<?php

if (isset($_SESSION['Logged']) && $email == "email@example.com") {

    //show the special menu example: admin menu

} else if (isset($_SESSION['Logged'])) {

    //show the members menu here

} else {

    //show the normal menu code  
}

?>
```

Happy to help!

Answer (score 0):

try this !!!

```
 if ( user logged in )
    {

        getloggedmenu();

    }

    else 
    {

      getUnloggedmenu()

    }

  public function getloogedmenu()

  {


   return  set you menu here;    
  }

  public function getUnloogedmenu()

  {     return set you menu here; 
  }
```